# Regular expression to replace string with an array value

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace a string with a corresponding value from an array. So for example:

```
$array=array(
    'food'=>'cornbread',
    'day'=>'wednesday'
);

$string='My favorite food is {food}';
```

This isn't right:

```
$string=preg_replace("/{(.*?)}/",$c[1],$string);
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace()` works with arrays. Search on the keys and replace with the values:

```
$string = str_replace(array_keys($array), $array, $string);
```